# Why colors did not appear in Key of heatmap.2()

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have a data that looks like this:

```
SC_LT34F_BM SC_LTSL_BM  SC_STSL_BM  SC_LTSL_FL  SC_STSL_FL  SC_MPP34F_BM    SC_ST34F_BM SC_CMP_BM   SC_MEP_BM   SC_GMP_BM   SC_CDP_BM   SC_MDP_BM   MLP_BM  MLP_FL  proB_CLP_BM proB_FrA_BM proB_FrBC_BM    preB_FrC_BM preB_FrD_BM B_FrE_BM    proB_CLP_FL proB_FrA_FL proB_FrBC_FL    preB_FrD_FL B_FrE_FL    B_T1_Sp B_T2_Sp B_T3_Sp B_Fo_Sp B_GC_Sp B_MZ_Sp B1a_Sp  B_FrF_BM    B_Fo_MLN    B_Fo_LN B_Fo_PC B1b_PC  B1a_PC  DC_8-_Th    DC_8+_Th    DC_4+_Sp    DC_8+_Sp    DC_8-4-11b-_Sp  DC_8-4-11b+_Sp  DC_pDC_8-_Sp    DC_pDC_8+_Sp    DC_4+_SLN   DC_8+_SLN   DC_8-4-11b-_SLN DC_8-4-11b+_SLN DC_pDC_8+_SLN   DC_IIhilang-103-11blo_SLN   DC_IIhilang-103-11b+_SLN    DC_IIhilang+103+11blo_SLN   DC_IIhilang+103-11b+_SLN    DC_4+_MLN   DC_8+_MLN   DC_8-4-11b-_MLN DC_8-4-11b+_MLN DC_pDC_8+_MLN   DC_LC_Sk    DC_103-11b+_Lv  DC_103+11b-_Lv  DC_103+11b-_LuLN    DC_103-11b+_LuLN    DC_103-11b+24+_Lu   DC_103+11b-_Lu  DC_103-11b+_PolyIC_Lu   DC_103+11b-_PolyIC_Lu   DC_103-11b+F4/80lo_Kd   DC_103+11b-_SI  DC_103+11b+_SI  DC_103+11b-_Salm3_SI    DC_103+11b+_Salm3_SI    MF_BM   MF_RP_Sp    MF_Lu   MF_103-11b+24-_Lu   MF_II+480lo_PC  MF_103-11b+_SI  MF_11cloSer_SI  MF_103-11b+_Salm3_SI    MF_11cloSer_Salm3_SI    MF_II-480hi_PC  MF_Microglia_CNS    MF_Thio5_II+480int_PC   MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC   MF_Thio5_II-480hi_PC    MF_Thio5_II+480lo_PC    Mo_6C+II-_BM    Mo_6C-II-_BM    Mo_6C+II-_Bl    Mo_6C+II+_Bl    Mo_6C-II-_Bl    Mo_6C-II+_Bl    Mo_6C-IIint_Bl  Mo_6C+II-_LN    GN_BM   GN_Bl   GN_Arth_BM  GN_Arth_SynF    GN_UrAc_PC  GN_Thio_PC  NK_Sp   NK_49CI-_Sp NK_49CI+_Sp NK_49H-_Sp  NK_49H+_Sp  NK_MCMV1_Sp NK_MCMV7_Sp NK_H+_MCMV1_Sp  NK_H+_MCMV7_Sp  NK_b2m-_Sp  NK_DAP10-_Sp    NK_DAP12-_Sp    preT_ETP_Th preT_ETP-2A_Th  preT_DN2_Th preT_DN2A_Th    preT_DN2B_Th    preT_DN2-3_Th   preT_DN3A_Th    preT_DN3B_Th    preT_DN3-4_Th   T_DN4_Th    T_ISP_Th    T_DP_Th T_DPbl_Th   T_DPsm_Th   T_DP69+_Th  T_4+8int_Th T_4SP69+_Th T_4SP24int_Th   T_4SP24-_Th T_4int8+_Th T_8SP69+_Th T_8SP24int_Th   T_8SP24-_Th T_4Nve_Sp   T_4Mem_Sp   T_4Mem44h62l_Sp T_4Nve_LN   T_4Mem_LN   T_4Mem44h62l_LN T_4Nve_PP   T_4Nve_MLN  T_4_LN_BDC  T_4_PLN_BDC T_4_Pa_BDC  T_4FP3-_Sp  T_4FP3+25+_Sp   T_4FP3+25+_AA   T_4FP3+25+_LN   T_8Nve_Sp   T_8Mem_Sp   T_8Nve_LN   T_8Mem_LN   T_8Nve_PP   T_8Nve_MLN  T_8Nve_Sp_OT1   T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d5_VSVOva T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d6_VSVOva T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d8_VSVOva T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d15_VSVOva    T_8Mem_Sp_OT1_d45_VSVOva    T_8Mem_Sp_OT1_d106_VSVOva   T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_12hr_LisOva   T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_24hr_LisOva   T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_48hr_LisOva   T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d6_LisOva T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d8_LisOva T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d10_LisOva    T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d15_LisOva    T_8Mem_Sp_OT1_d45_LisOva    T_8Mem_Sp_OT1_d100_LisOva   NKT_44-NK1_1-_Th    NKT_44+NK1_1-_Th    NKT_44+NK1_1+_Th    NKT_4+_Sp   NKT_4-_Sp   NKT_4+_Lv   NKT_4-_Lv   Tgd_Th  Tgd_vg1+vd6-24ahi_Th    Tgd_vg1+vd6+24ahi_Th    Tgd_vg2+24ahi_Th    Tgd_vg2+24ahi_e17_Th    Tgd_vg3+24ahi_e17_Th    Tgd_vg5+24ahi_Th    Tgd_vg1+vd6-24alo_Th    Tgd_vg1+vd6+24alo_Th    Tgd_vg2+24alo_Th    Tgd_vg3+24alo_e17_Th    Tgd_Sp  Tgd_vg2-_Sp Tgd_vg2-_act_Sp Tgd_vg2+_Sp Tgd_vg2+_act_Sp Tgd_vg2-_Sp_TCRbko  Tgd_vg2+_Sp_TCRbko  Tgd_vg5-_IEL    Tgd_vg5+_IEL    Tgd_vg5-_act_IEL    Tgd_vg5+_act_IEL    Ep_MEChi_Th Fi_MTS15+_Th    Fi_Sk   FRC_MLN FRC_SLN LEC_MLN LEC_SLN BEC_MLN BEC_SLN St_31-38-44-_SLN
1415806_at Plat 27.9185 36.5107 33.0332 30.6177 29.9747 28.8708 30.3841 37.5277 30.5361 32.6895 29.4836 27.9885 29.4244 26.5173 35.0402 31.544  30.9292 29.8665 35.6304 33.0442 26.7101 28.2309 30.9805 28.6152 31.8907 32.0462 34.8866 33.0858 35.7239 35.2472 34.3717 29.8923 39.6809 41.3769 42.2323 39.081  33.5901 35.0953 30.3213 27.7287 34.1493 37.4285 32.0074 39.7632 33.5368 30.3562 45.2669 40.6258 195.136 103.185 39.0732 80.0762 153.337 365.59  78.3391 39.9067 44.3187 56.1457 33.6093 41.5659 366.436 40.771  32.906  150.567 55.6916 105.192 44.2745 185.212 76.1094 28.6436 36.086  68.2284 39.585  119.956 26.9137 38.7293 33.0461 60.3476 28.3998 34.0431 32.9896 65.296  59.0182 28.654  40.783  33.7108 29.0525 29.3948 31.408  31.5986 35.9317 31.184  29.0688 34.2658 33.5081 32.2015 35.6911 41.8463 44.3161 38.3131 51.4425 51.4854 42.5922 40.787  39.072  34.6637 33.343  33.0619 36.7676 37.9347 31.0312 35.6631 35.7623 37.7508 33.1229 33.6179 41.1347 32.8821 35.5274 34.5783 29.3629 37.1282 32.6213 29.7352 31.6801 30.03   37.6091 37.3695 35.7894 39.4483 42.3723 41.7823 31.979  33.1111 34.9302 36.7907 34.9848 32.0475 41.4716 37.722  35.7637 43.4169 40.778  34.4366 47.119  41.7399 46.3535 30.093  31.4636 41.9103 46.1681 37.7144 34.474  42.1673 47.1553 37.3054 49.77   40.0073 33.6125 34.3092 38.0424 42.9508 39.9314 55.4645 36.0474 50.1869 38.7767 32.3656 31.0418 27.0207 30.6182 33.8824 42.901  32.0133 39.7088 37.3634 33.07   33.4334 43.9524 35.59   37.7714 42.626  33.3944 33.1647 31.626  39.8802 28.3281 40.7664 34.782  34.9716 31.0598 43.7914 32.7444 35.9125 38.8265 38.2612 32.2323 40.2928 36.7945 34.991  37.4216 40.4704 39.3888 30.0384 105.793 2526.44 640.249 242.364 131.67  1064.84 1056.81 208.29  157.891 271.912
1415899_at Junb 104.359 116.588 117.664 113.224 66.2672 86.464  81.6396 76.6304 100.614 116.538 118.284 129.816 101.239 89.2805 99.7887 125.883 112.003 99.5811 118.3   178.751 87.5629 70.5608 120.18  101.577 137.816 123.722 125.728 168.945 138.178 153.402 104.895 175.298 137.421 113.447 117.66  129.752 143.541 146.186 428.249 412.473 385.435 339.74  473.701 507.498 220.07  194.76  667.376 488.267 354.873 635.98  193.976 507.981 667.498 442.459 449.715 639.196 574.944 542.865 687.359 150.271 889.725 1169.58 459.569 374.314 461.532 1206.02 675.481 1130.99 849.501 280.516 979.627 1324.66 671.702 1053.9  152.166 350.176 337.302 826.052 513.71  1469.49 1517.93 1238.98 1257.99 330.983 1478.1  238.873 212.152 208.743 405.299 236.767 278.17  341.064 345.308 281.135 393.439 302.634 682.04  325.536 960.248 321.11  1291.57 883.89  885.596 219.172 175.986 216.132 278.688 295.721 275.892 215.793 299.334 331.465 185.401 220.586 204.986 456.516 378.278 226.349 454.313 425.804 232.92  146.899 110.746 112.351 125.992 103.248 150.85  94.4725 135.077 229.705 165.416 223.929 232.708 195.205 142.457 182.395 144.899 202.909 193.86  205.682 570.849 231.047 194.275 441.833 382.466 210.373 192.348 221.835 248.175 209.08  276.048 1647.57 249.185 263.404 191.867 211.169 157.855 283.887 155.999 156.376 168.494 222.407 175.15  175.776 180.29  216.886 284.49  206.288 178.744 188.286 163.138 180.242 205.278 286.698 151.971 255.359 293.267 662.865 772.192 520.293 706.199 559.661 146.378 177.677 180.272 144.715 107.154 135.916 149.646 251.437 214.44  328.079 189.697 166.164 252.097 254.642 277.984 260.566 294.951 244.528 709.615 765.502 148.709 310.161 404.302 1408.72 1158.08 1199.58 1694.65 812.419 1004.32 950.417 1083.41 1061.59
..(more)...
```

With the following code:

```
library(gplots);
library(RColorBrewer);

dat <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wM7WxEvY",sep="\t",na.strings="NA",header=TRUE)
dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
dat.log <- log2(dat);

# Clustering and distance function
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="ward")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="maximum")

nofval <- length(unique(as.vector(as.matrix(dat.log))));
hmcols <- rev(redblue(nofval));

pdf(file="temp.pdf",width=50,height=40);
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat.log),Colv=FALSE,lhei = c(0.25,4),density.info="none",scale="none",margin=c(10,10),col=hmcols,symkey=F,trace="none",dendrogram="row",keysize=0.3,hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc);
dev.off();
```

It produces this image:
[image]

Note that at the top left the colors of KEY did not appear at all.
What's the problem with my code above?
How can I correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colours are being parsed at very high resolution. You have assigned a colour gradient to every value in your matrix, total of 17410. Try decreasing the colour gradient to 128 or 256: `col=bluered(256)`.

Alternatively, increase the key size `keysize=1` to display the higher colour gradient.